# Change Background color and font color

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to change my `WebView`'s background color and font size.

Comment: You can change the background color and font size but not the font color.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that you have defined your webview in an XML layout resource you can do the following:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
myWebView.getSettings.setDefaultFontSize(10);
```

You may also want to enable javascript and create a simple WebClient to handle page loading

Hope it helps!

Comment: I didn't see any thing regarding changing font color in the API documentation. I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could call some javascript that would modify the CSS of the loaded page.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you can't - unless you control the html data displayed.

The font and background are controlled by the html data feed to the Webview and not the Webview itself.