# How to set backGround color Black and text white in android webview

Tags: android

```
package com.example.webviewtheme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView webview1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webview1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        String rawHTML = "<HTML>"+  
         "<body style='color: #000000; background-color: #ffffff'><h1>Hello Android </h1></body>"+  
     "</HTML>";
        webview1.setBackgroundColor(00000000);
        webview1.loadData(rawHTML, "text/HTML", "UTF-8");
    }

}
```

This is My code i want to set background color black and text white of webView i have tried to apply In Html But Unable to get Out put please help me  how to set Night Mode in Webview text and backGround

Comment: Try these links [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225296/how-set-text-color-of-webview-in-android) and [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254970/changing-text-color-in-a-webview) and [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389446/android-webview-changing-backcolor-and-font-color)

Comment: You can check in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37645059/11060846)

Answer (score 10):

use this

```
webview1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    String rawHTML = "<HTML>"+ 
     "<head>"+"<style  type=\"text/css\">"+
     "body,h1{color: #000000;"+
     "background-color: #ffffff;}"+
     "</style></head>"+
     "<body><h1>Hello Android </h1></body>"+  
 "</HTML>";
    webview1.loadData(rawHTML, "text/html; charset=UTF-8",null);
```

**UPDATE 20/June:**

if you want to change web page css after it's load finished (for example when load webPageAddress with `loadUrl`) you can do it like this:

- set javaScript enable on `webView`

  ```
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  ```
- set listener on page load finish

  ```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Inject CSS on PageFinished
        injectCSS();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
     }
  });
  ```
- inject CSS

  ```
  private void injectCSS() {
    webView.loadUrl(
      "javascript:document.body.style.setProperty(\"color\", \"white\");"
    );
    webView.loadUrl(
      "javascript:document.body.style.setProperty(\"background-color\", \"black\");"
    );
  }
  ```

Comment: How we can do same this with loadUrl, as i am using external url for load data in webview

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that will inject Javascript into a webpage to make it invert colors:

```
String js ="javascript: ("
                    +"function () { "

                    +"var css = 'html {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);' +"
                    +"    '-moz-filter: invert(100%);' + "
                    +"    '-o-filter: invert(100%);' + "
                    +"    '-ms-filter: invert(100%); }',"

                    +"head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],"
                    +"style = document.createElement('style');"

                    +"if (!window.counter) { window.counter = 1;} else  { window.counter ++;"
                    +"if (window.counter % 2 == 0) { var css ='html {-webkit-filter: invert(0%); -moz-filter:    invert(0%); -o-filter: invert(0%); -ms-filter: invert(0%); }'}"
                    +"};"

                    +"style.type = 'text/css';"
                    +"if (style.styleSheet){"
                    +"style.styleSheet.cssText = css;"
                    +"} else {"
                    +"style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));"
                    +"}"

                    //injecting the css to the head
                    +"head.appendChild(style);"
                    +"}());";

                    CustomWebView.this.loadUrl(js);
```

Comment: this filter is good, but on my 4.4 device it makes the text blurry.

Answer (score 2):

`webview.setBackgroundColor(0)` makes webview transparent.

You will need to set bg color black in the HTML tag bg.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is not in document, and not recommended, but it will work:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    webview.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_S%C3%B6derberg");
    try {
        Class clsWebSettingsClassic = 
            getClassLoader().loadClass("android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic");
        Method md = clsWebSettingsClassic.getMethod(
                "setProperty", String.class, String.class);
        md.invoke(webview.getSettings(), "inverted", "true");
        md.invoke(webview.getSettings(), "inverted_contrast", "1");
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

This will do inverted rendering to WebView.
The range of "inverted_contrast" is about 1 to 30 (not very sure).
The result tested with android 4.2:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsKjX.png

Comment: it is also working for me...using this color of font and other colors are being black or white... can we get color of that? i need like night mode in webview... thanks.!!

Comment: it throws ClassNotFoundException. I have looked at debugger - getSettings() returns WebSettings instance.

Answer (score 1):

Give the following in java class

```
webView1.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

and set the colour of text in xml

Answer (score 1):

in XML

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/web"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

in java code

```
String str="<div style=\'background-color:transparent;padding: 5px ;color:#white'>Enter text to display in web view</div";
WebView web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
web.loadData(str,"text/html","utf-8");
web.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Actully i want to apply Theme setting for day Mode And Night mode .

Answer (score 0):

Use this for webview backgroundColor:

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webview1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);

        String text = "<html><head>"
                  + "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #fff; background-color: #000;}"
                  + "</style></head>"
                  + "<body>"                          
                  + "Helloo Andorid"
                  + "</body></html>";

        webview1.loadData(text, "text/html", "utf-8");
        webview1.setBackgroundColor(00000000);
    }

}
```

It's works for me..

Comment: i have Puted another Button for Day Mode In which i have set backGround white how i will do this

Comment: you have to apply background white for same webview?

Answer (score 0):

*Hai this may help you*

```
dialogMesage.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

*or*

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invert colors of a `WebView` using its parent.

1. You need to implement inversion in parent. I'm using a `FrameLayout`, but you can use some other form of layout.

   ```java
   public class WebViewInverter extends FrameLayout {
        public WebViewInverter(Context context) {
           super(context);
           init();
       }

       public WebViewInverter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
           init();
       }

       public WebViewInverter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
           init();
       }

       public WebViewInverter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
           init();
       }

       private boolean nightMode = false;

       private Paint paint = new Paint(); 
       private ColorFilter cf;
       private Rect inversionRect;

       @Override protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas c){
               inversionRect = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
               Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
               Canvas cc = new Canvas(b);
               super.dispatchDraw(cc);
               paint.setColorFilter(null);
               c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, paint);
               paint.setColorFilter(cf);
               c.drawBitmap(b, inversionRect, inversionRect, paint);
       }

       private void init(){
           float[] mat = new float[]
           {
               -1,  0,  0, 0,  255,
                0, -1,  0, 0,  255,
                0,  0, -1, 0,  255,
                0,  0,  0, 1,  0
           };
           cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(mat));
       }

   }
   ```
2. Place Your `WebView` inside inverter in your layout's file:

   ```xml
   <your.package.name.WebViewInverter
       android:id="@+id/view_inverter"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/reader_side_margins"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reader_top_margin"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/reader_side_margins"
       android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/reader_bottom_margin">

       <ru.yandex.reader.widget.ReaderView
           android:id="@+id/view_reader"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   </your.package.name.WebViewInverter>
   ```

The `WebView` should be inverted.

Answer (score -1):

Android have built-in theme for night mode called **Theme.AppCompat.DayNight** theme

`<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Blah blah -->
</style>`

To know more, how to implement this functionality check out the link below

https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94