# How to create a Night mode of WebView content Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-night-mode

I am working in a Browser android app . How to  do nightmode a website view when it is loaded into a WebView ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Zahirul Have you found solution?

Comment: @hpAndro didn't get good solution. But we used some css that was slow .

Comment: by CSS you got the result? I mean I tried with invert color by CSS but it changes the icon colors too. so that cause problem. Can you please help for the same...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974675/how-to-set-background-color-black-and-text-white-in-android-webview

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a button to change it to nightmode with Custom Css?